# Wordpress Content Alignment Problem

Tags: wordpress, widget, alignment

I've added a Wordpress "contact us" page to my web site. But i couldnt align the content normally. I added a contact form and a google maps iframe. But i cant shown them at the same level together. The page's sidebar is hidden and I dont need it. How can this problem be solved?

http://www.mersinhatayrestaurant.com/?page_id=10

I also try using tables

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>[si-contact-form form='1']</td>

<td>
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=tr&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Hatay+Restaurant,+Yeni%C5%9Fehir,+Adnan+Menderes+Bulvar%C4%B1,+Mersin,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=36.804204,34.638567&amp;sspn=0.194075,0.528374&amp;g=mersin&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Hatay+Restaurant,&amp;hnear=Adnan+Menderes+Blv,+Mersin%2FYeni%C5%9Fehir,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;ll=36.778016,34.586682&amp;spn=0.006295,0.011489&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

But nothing changed. I am waiting for your solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a float:left on both the iframe and div for the contact form without the table.  or add a vertical-align: top; to the TD with the contact form.  you have statically assigned height and width to iframe, and if that is taller than the contact form, then it will fill the entire TD cell and the contact form will move to the bottom as the default behavior for TD is vertical-align: bottom;

EDIT:

Added the vertical align dynamically to your site and it worked, just add it in below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">[si-contact-form form='1']</td>

    <td>
    <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=tr&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Hatay+Restaurant,+Yeni%C5%9Fehir,+Adnan+Menderes+Bulvar%C4%B1,+Mersin,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=36.804204,34.638567&amp;sspn=0.194075,0.528374&amp;g=mersin&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Hatay+Restaurant,&amp;hnear=Adnan+Menderes+Blv,+Mersin%2FYeni%C5%9Fehir,+T%C3%BCrkiye&amp;ll=36.778016,34.586682&amp;spn=0.006295,0.011489&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Omer Gencay, mark as answer if solved your issue otherwise people won't keep helping you...